# Why my converter doesn't count the last digit?

Tags: c, string, for-loop, decimal, roman-numerals

This program is about converting Roman number to decimal number. The program can convert the alphabet to number but it can not process the last roman digit. I think my flow is alright but the output is not right. Can any body give me a helping hand?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int roman_to_int(const char s[], int length) {
    // Please complete the function body
    
    int ans = 0, value[length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        
        switch (s[i]) {
        
            case 'I': value[i] = 1; break;
            case 'V': value[i] = 5; break;
            case 'X': value[i] = 10; break;
            case 'L': value[i] = 50; break;
            case 'C': value[i] = 100; break;
            case 'D': value[i] = 500; break;
            case 'M': value[i] = 1000; break;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
     
        if (value[i] >= value[i+1])
            ans += value[i];
        else {
            ans = ans + value[i+1] - value[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    char roman_num[] = "III";
    char roman_num_2[] = "CXXIII";
    char roman_num_3[] = "MMMCDLIX";

    printf("roman_to_int(%s) = %d\n", roman_num,
           roman_to_int(roman_num, strlen(roman_num)));
    printf("roman_to_int(%s) = %d\n", roman_num_2,
           roman_to_int(roman_num_2, strlen(roman_num_2)));
    printf("roman_to_int(%s) = %d\n", roman_num_3,
           roman_to_int(roman_num_3, strlen(roman_num_3)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the value of the last roman digit after the end of the second loop.

As an alternative, you could make `value` on entry longer than `n` and set the last entry to `0` so you won't need the make a special case of the last roman digit.

Note that you should also handle the case of unrecognised roman digits: either by ignoring them or by returning an error code, such as a negative value `-1`.

It is also simpler for `roman_to_int` to take a null terminated C string and compute the length there.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int roman_to_int(const char s[]) {
    // Please complete the function body
    int length = strlen(s);
    int ans = 0, value[length + 1];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        switch (s[i]) {
            case 'I': value[i] = 1; break;
            case 'V': value[i] = 5; break;
            case 'X': value[i] = 10; break;
            case 'L': value[i] = 50; break;
            case 'C': value[i] = 100; break;
            case 'D': value[i] = 500; break;
            case 'M': value[i] = 1000; break;
            default: return -1;
        }
    }
    value[length] = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (value[i] >= value[i + 1])
            ans += value[i];
        else
            ans -= value[i];
    }
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    char roman_num[] = "III";
    char roman_num_2[] = "CXXIII";
    char roman_num_3[] = "MMMCDLIX";
    char roman_num_4[] = "MMMCDLIZ";  // error

    printf("roman_to_int(%s) = %d\n", roman_num, roman_to_int(roman_num));
    printf("roman_to_int(%s) = %d\n", roman_num_2, roman_to_int(roman_num_2));
    printf("roman_to_int(%s) = %d\n", roman_num_3, roman_to_int(roman_num_3));
    printf("roman_to_int(%s) = %d\n", roman_num_4, roman_to_int(roman_num_4));
    return 0;
}
```